# Changing integer to floating point and adding decimal point

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm working with SQL on Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008.

In a nut shell, I'm receiving data on coordinates as `115949833` and I need it to output as `115.949833` because I need to be able to calculate the mileage between the latitude and longitude coordinates. Both the longitude and latitude values are saved as integers with no decimal places. I was trying to change it to a string so I could use a substring to concatenate and convert it into a floating point. I've already figured out the formula for the mileage between lat and long values but its not accurate because of the issue with the decimal point.

Here's the code I used for the longitude:

`Cast(substring(str(longitude,1,not null),1,3)+'.'+substring(str(longitude,4,not null),4,9) as float) as longitude`

It keeps telling me I have an incorrect syntax near `CAST`.

I've been doing a lot of research and still couldn't find an exact way of performing this task. If anyone could provide any feedback, tips, help, etc. It would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

***EDIT: I need the entire column named "Longitude" to be converted into a floating point or to somehow display a decimal after the 3rd character and the entire column named "Latitude" to display a decimal after the 2nd character.

So for example right now my columns show:

Latitude                 Longitude 
36158500                 115949833
36340000                 115914667
36153488                 115944875

and I need it to look like this:

Latitude                 Longitude 
36.158500                 115.949833 
36.340000                 115.914667 
36.153488                 115.944875

****EDIT****
So using Tim Lehner's Answer, I've used my code and implemented his answer, but now I need to figure out how to get it to show the mileage using the new Latitude and Longitude columns... I created a few temp table's to store the information I wanted in based on specific radio_name's but I can't pull the info from those temp tables using Tim's Answer.

**Here's the code I'm using:** 
         USE [system]
         GO
         With CTE as 
         (SELECT * FROM AVL 
         WHERE (DATE_TIME between '01/30/2013 00:00:00' AND 
         '01/30/2013 23:59:59') AND radio_name = 'MAS7') 
        CTE2 as 
        (select *,row_number() over(partition by Vehicle_ID order by Date_Time) as RN
        FROM CTE)

```
      SELECT *, sqrt((69.1*(previous.Latitude - next.Latitude))*
     (69.1*(previous.Latitude-next.Latitude)) + 
     (69.1*(previous.Longitude-next.Longitude)) *
     cos(next.Latitude/57.3) * (69.1*(previous.longitude-next.Longitude)) *
     cos(next.Latitude/57.3)) as Miles

    From CTE2 as Previous
    Join CTE2 as Next
    On previous.Vehicle_ID = Next.Vehicle_ID
    AND Previous.RN = 
    Next.RN - 1
    SELECT CAST(Latitude / 1000000.0 as decimal(10, 6)) as Latitude, 
    cast(Longitude / 1000000.0 as decimal(10, 6)) as Longitude
    from AVL
```

The actual code itself does work and function properly but the mileage calculation is using the original whole latitude/longitude numbers and not the updated numbers that have the decimal point.

I tried plugging in CTE2 in the last statement instead of AVL and it says it's an invalid object name. Any pointers or tips?...

Comment: You have 5 left parentheses and 6 right ones, so even if nothing else is wrong that would cause an error.

Comment: A CTE can only be used by the statement directly following it. You might consider creating a new question for this issue, and that of calculating distance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use datatypes to my advantage:

```
select 115949833 / 1000000.0
-- returns 115.949833000
```

You can then round/truncate to your spec.

Adding the decimal point to the divisor will promote the output of this operation to `numeric` per the rules of [datatype precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx).

**UPDATE**

Per your test data, you might use a query like this:

```
select cast(Latitude / 1000000.0 as decimal(10, 6)) as Latitude
  , cast(Longitude / 1000000.0 as decimal(10, 6)) as Longitude
from MyTable

/*
Returns:
Latitude    Longitude
36.158500   115.949833
36.340000   115.914667
36.153488   115.944875
*/
```

Comment: Awesome. That worked. :) Thank you so much! Question though - Can I implement this using a temp. table?...

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you. Selecting from a temp table shouldn't make any difference in this logic, if that's better for your environment.

Comment: I tried to implement it using a temp table called CTE2 and it keeps telling me its an invalid object name. Just saw your post. Good point.

Answer (score 1):

you always want to add the dot after the 3rd character?  use the [STUFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) function

```
DECLARE @v VARCHAR(100)
SELECT @v = '115949833'

SELECT CONVERT(FLOAT,(STUFF(@v,4,0,'.')))
```

Output

115.949833

Another way is to multiply by 0.000001

```
DECLARE @v VARCHAR(100)
SELECT @v = '115949833'


SELECT CONVERT(INT,@v)  * 0.000001
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `STUFF`:

```
select stuff(longitude,4,0,'.') from table
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/8382).

And if you need it to be float, then just add cast:

```
select cast(stuff(longitude,4,0,'.') as float)  from table
```

Good luck.

Comment: I need the entire column named "Longitude" to add a decimal point after the 3rd character, not just '115949833'. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT round(substring(longitude,1,3)+'.'+substring(longitude,4,6),6)
FROM TableName
```

Comment: I tried this and this is the error I'm receiving: "Argument data type int is invalid for argument 1 of substring function." - I'm pretty sure you can't use the substring function on a integer, which was why I was trying to convert it to a string first and then to a floating point to then use the substring function.

Comment: you are correct, I didn't notice that the data started out as a number, the answer that is marked is the best answer.